# Higher push forwards and etale cohomology

Tags: etale-cohomology

On the page 335 of Lei Fu's book on Etale cohomology theory (2nd edition)(in the proof of Lemma 7.3.5),
he insists the following:

Let $f: X' \rightarrow X$ be a surjective morphism. Then,
$$
H^q_{et}(X, Rf_* \mathcal{F}) \simeq H^q_{et}(X', \mathcal{F}).
$$

I guess this is related to the Leray spectral sequence,
but I don't know why the above two are isomorphic. Can someone explain this?

Comment: @TimoKeller: By writing $Rf_*\mathcal F$, I suspect that HY..  means the direct image _complex_ which is not necessarily concentrated in degree 0.

Comment: @ACL: This is exactly the form written in the book. I think Fu means the higher direct image complex.